# htaccess put site into maintenance, deny all but my own IP

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I want to put my webpage into maintenance so I replace my original htaccess file with this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /maintenance/maintenance.php
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

Have read a lot of threads before posting and this is what i gathered would be the correct solution, but I don´t get it to work. If I don´t allow from my own IP I get an Error 500 (meaning that that is what my visitors would see) and if I do use my IP I get and Error 403 (and I dont even reach my maintenance page it sais I´m not allowed there either).

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution that worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#ip is not your ip. Change ip to see maintenance page
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.222\.333\.444$

#requests made not to maintenance.php ... 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$

#rewrite to maintenance.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess you posted works for me with `Allow from 127.0.0.1`, but you need an additional .htaccess in the `maintenance` directory, allowing access to the `maintenance.php` error document

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my tips, paste this code into the `.htaccess` of your site, to make all the pages of your domain remapping into `/maintenance.html` file, if the viewer's I.P. isn't the same as yours:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^000\.111\.222\.333
RewriteCond ^(.*) /maintenance.html
```

Keep noted that the numbers `000\.111\.222\.333` must be changed as your I.P. address, and create a `/maintenance.html` file where your pages will be remapped.