# Having set an "Under Construction" page while setting up WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am setting up an WordPress store and while doing this, we have to put an Under Construction page. But by simply adding an index.html file, Wordpress index.php won't work anymore so I cannot develop the site anymore.

What't the best way to solve this ? Thank you.

Comment: I personally wouldn't add an 'under construction' page. It's an invitation for search engines to demote your site. Develop your site away from a live environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `.htaccess` file to display a [maintenance page to all IP addresses except your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817783/htaccess-put-site-into-maintenance-deny-all-but-my-own-ip).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.5$ # More than one IP needed?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use a plug-in, you can add this code to your themes header.php file.

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    header("Location: http://example.com/unauthorized.html");
}
```

You can also use wp_redirect if you'd like

```
wp_redirect('http://example.com/unauthorized.html', '302');
```

Its better than restricting it to a specific IP as you can work on the site from any IP. Just need to login by visiting wp-admin.

Comment: Worth noting with this method that the setting for 'Anyone can register' would want to be off.